# NASA API into table in excel

Tags: api, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to download weather related data using the Nasa API into excel using powerquery.
I'm trying to query wind speed at 50 metres, the string for which is

https://power.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/v1/DataAccess.py?&request=execute&tempAverage=DAILY&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=WS50M&userCommunity=SB&lon=142&lat=-38&startDate=20170101&endDate=20201231&outputList=JSON&user=DOCUMENTATION

I know this is the correct string because when I paste this as a url into my chrome browser, I get the desired output in JSON. However, when I try to get the output into a table in excel, I get a mere 2 records. Something is clearly amiss.
Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: then I think you should share your code because you're right your url is working fine..If you share your code it would be easy to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, utilize o power Query do excel.

let
Fonte = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://power.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/v1/DataAccess.py?&request=execute&tempAverage=DAILY&identifier=SinglePoint&parameters=WS50M&userCommunity=SB&lon=142&lat=-38&startDate=20170101&endDate=20201231&outputList=JSON&user=DOCUMENTATION")),
features = Fonte[features],
features1 = features{0},
properties = features1[properties],
parameter = properties[parameter],
WS50M = parameter[WS50M]
in
WS50M

Comment: SO is an English only site, please translate your explanation.